# Facing error when trying to copy original website in into development website

Tags: database, wordpress, ubuntu, server, civicrm

Fatal error:

> Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [-26: DB Error: insufficient permissions
> thrown in
> /var/www/ecocentredev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php
> on line 971

I am Expecting  to start a site. I also make user for that website and grant all the permission.

Comment: Check your database user

Comment: Also note there is a dedicated civicrm channel https://civicrm.stackexchange.com if you need more specific CiviCRM advice